# four period crossover design in lmer or lme4

Tags: lme4-nlme, crossover-study

Our experimental setting is a four-period crossover design: the table below indicates typical types of experimental data.

```
Subj Treat Period Seq AUClast 
A01  R     1      A   356 
A01  R     3      A   565 
A01  T     2      A   596 
A01  T     4      A   553 
A02  R     1      A   501 
A02  R     3      A   648 
A02  T     2      A   467 
A02  T     4      A   400 
A03  R     1      A   392 
A03  R     3      A   585 
A03  T     2      A   496 
A03  T     4      A   402 
A04  R     1      A   577 
A04  R     3      A   455 
A04  T     2      A   460 
A04  T     4      A   388 
A05  R     1      A   443 
A05  R     3      A   605 
.....
B19  T     1      B   775 
B19  T     3      B   835 
B20  R     2      B   1120 
B20  R     4      B   1513 
B20  T     1      B   1352 
B20  T     3      B   1150
```

There are two groups of subjects. In A group, subjects get treatment T,R,T,R with respect to Period 1, Period2, Period3, Period 4. The other group's subjects have treatment R,T,R,T with respect to Period 1, Period2, Period3, Period 4. In this experiment,

- the Fixed model is: `int+Sequence+Treatment+Period`
- the Random/Repeated model is: `TreatmentSubject+PeriodTreatment*Subject`

The below formulation is my trial formulation.

```
AUClast ~ Seq+Treat+Period+(1|Subj)
```

This formula works well in 2x2 crossover design. But in the case of 2x4 crossover, it doesn't work. How can I change the above equation into lmer or lme4?

Comment: can you be more specific about what "doesn't work" means?

Comment: In the case of 2x2 crossover design, results of the formula are same as sas and winnonlin which are standard program in phamarco area.